# First Question from New User to Bitcoin

Tags: security

What is Bitcoin?
I received a "congratulations" message from George Green saying I have a new Bitcoin transaction and to click a link to "get it."

Payout is:  $29,970.07 and instructions say I need to withdraw this money within 24 hours, and to create an application to exchange BTC in USD, and that funds have been transferred to a cryptocurency exchange Binance, and to make a cryptocurrency exchange to receive funds right now.  Binance Exchange fee is -0.25%; cost of conversion 64$.

IS THIS LEGITIMATE AND SAFE?!

Where does the money come from?

Comment: A proposed an edit to remove the question about [reputation.](/help/whats-reputation) Visit the help pages to learn how this site works; the link is to the page about reputation and how to earn it.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here about possible scams. A message promising you money for clicking on a link is almost certainly a scam, but without more details, all we can say for sure is that if it sounds too good to be true, it probably is.